# How to /execute a command at an entity's death location? (java 1.13+)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been creating a minigame in Minecraft for a while now and I wanted to create custom death effects for some mobs. For example, if a zombie dies, It should immediately /summon TNT at its death position. I haven't found any information on how to do this in the newer versions (1.13+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First summon a Zombie with a tag:

```
summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {Tags:["zo"]}
```

Then summon an armor stand that is invisible, has no gravity, and is a marker, that as well has a tag:

```
summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {NoGravity:1,Invisible:1,Marker:1,Tags:["as"]}
```

In a repeating command block tp the armorstand to the tagged zombie:

```
tp @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,tag=as] @e[type=husk,tag=zo,limit=1]
```

Then for the tnt part.

You need a repeating command block that is powered by a Redstone block next to it with the command:

```
execute unless entity @e[tag=zo] run setblock ~1 ~ ~ air
```

After this block there should be a chain block that will summon the tnt, this block should be `chain`, `conditional`, and `always active`:

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,tag=as] run summon tnt
```

The first `execute` command executes only if there are no entities with the tag: zo, then removes its source block. The second executes only if the first one succeeds and summons tnt at the location of the armor stand. You can add an additional `conditional` command block afterward to remove the armor stand. And when `summoning` the two entities you can put that in a command blockchain as well, here you could add the Redstone block that activates the execute command chain.